# How to identify if an option was supplied without a value with Symfony Console?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-console

With the Symfony3 Console, how can I tell when a user supplied an option, but supplied it without a value?  As opposed to not supplying the option at all?

As an example, take the following console configuration.

```php
<?php

class MyCommand extends \Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command
{
    // ...

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('test')
            ->setDescription('update an existing operation.')
            ->addOption(
                'option',
                null,
                InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL,
                'The ID of the operation to update.'
            );
    }
}
```

The command help will illustrate the option as `--option[=OPTION]`, so I can call this the following ways.

```sh
bin/console test
bin/console test --option
bin/console test --option=foo
```

However, `$input->getOption()` will return `NULL` in the first two cases.  I expected in the second case that it would return `TRUE`, or something to indicate the option was supplied.

So I don't know how to identify the difference the option not being supplied at all, and it being supplied but without a value.

If there is no way to tell the difference, what is the use-case for `InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Symfony 3.4, you can just set the default to `false` and check:

1. if the value is `false` the option doesn't exist
2. if the value is `null` the option exists without a value
3. otherwise it has its value

e.g.

```
$this->addOption('force', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Force something', false);

$force = $input->getOption('force') !== false;
```

Comment: This works, and is safer than the current accepted answer because this method works with shortcuts correctly.

Comment: Yes, with newer version of Symfony, this is definitely is preferred solution.

Comment: No longer correct since Symfony 4.4. Whether I pass the option, or not, the value is always NULL, unless specified.

Answer (score 11):

You're combining two things together. Option with no value `InputOption::VALUE_NONE` and an option with an optional value `InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL`.

The documentation says: http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/input.html

> There is nothing forbidding you to create a command with an option that optionally accepts a value. However, there is no way you can distinguish when the option was used without a value (command --language) or when it wasn't used at all (command). In both cases, the value retrieved for the option will be null.

This describes exactly your case.

You can't distinguish when a parameter wasn't passed at all or was passed but with no value. That's what `InputOption::VALUE_NONE` was made for.

Depending on your usecase you can supply a default value for a parameter which will be used in `console test` and `console test --option` cases.

Also note, that `addOption` takes as an argument a shortcut as the second argument.

```
public function addOption($name, $shortcut = null, $mode = null, $description = '', $default = null)
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It still raises the question (not at you, but just in general,) why does this feature exists? I.e. Why offer the the ability for an option to have an optional value if the command can only identify the option was provided when it has a value. How does someone put that to good use?

Comment: Simple - switches! `command` would simply run it, `command --verbose` would run it verbose.

Comment: `$input->getOption('switch-option')` should either return `true` or `false` based on its existence.

Answer (score 8):

Edit on 6/10/21: This only applies to Symfony 3.3 and below. The correct answer is now the one provided by ScorpioT1000

After poking around in `Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface`, I discovered the `getParameterOption()` method which provides the ability to differentiate between an option not used, an option used without a value, and an option used with a value.

In the command's `configure()` method:

`$this->addOption('test', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL);`

In the command's `execute()` method:

`$test = $input->getOption('test'); $rawTest = $input->getParameterOption('--test');`

Produces the following values for the given command lines:

`> bin/console some:cmd`

`$test` => `null`

`$rawTest` => `false`

`> bin/console some:cmd --test`

`$test` => `null`

`$rawTest` => `null`

`> bin/console some:cmd --test=something`

`$test` => `"something"`

`$rawTest` => `"something"`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the other answers didn't work for me. What worked for me was:

```php
if (is_null($input->getParameterOption('--zip', 'NOT_SET'))) {
  // --zip without a value.
}
```